# bootstrap not getting dismissable warning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap. From the tutorials I've seen

```
<div  class="alert alert-warning" style="margin-left: 480px;margin-top: 20px;width: 500px;">
 Warning Message Here 
</div>
```

This should give me a dismissable warning message.

But I'm getting a warning message, but not dismissable.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use like this -

```
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in"  style="margin-left: 480px;margin-top: 20px;width: 500px;">
   <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
   <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>  Warning Message Here 
</div>
```

See more [**details**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts)

Answer (score 1):

yes you miss the closing button and javascript code for that.

button tag will give you x symbol and you need to add correct classes.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
 Warning message here
</div>
```